# Can we pass dynamic values within values in Scenario Outline in Karate

Tags: api, karate

```
Scenario Outline: User payload validation

Given url usermessagesAPI
* request
"""
 {
  "first_name" : "<first_name>",
  "last_name" : "<last_name>",
  "transaction_id" : "<transaction_id>,
  "user_message" : "<user_message>"
 }
"""
When method POST
Then assert responseStatus == 202

Examples:
|first_name|last_name|transaction_id|user_message|
|xyz|xyz|87690|<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><MsgId>201060024</MsgId><CreDtTm>2020-04-   14T13:45:02</CreDtTm>|
|abc|abc|76565|<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><MsgId>7858757</MsgId><CreDtTm>2022-04-14T13:45:02</CreDtTm>| */
```

In the above example, how do I pass random values for MsgId and CreDtTm which are within the XML message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data within the `Examples:` is fixed and cannot be changed at run-time. You can however do modifications within the `Scenario Outline` block. So I think you can achieve what you want. Here is an example:

```
Feature:

Scenario Outline:
* def rand = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
* xml payload = message
* karate.set('payload', '/root/CreDtTm', rand)
* print payload

Examples:
| message |
| <root><MsgId>201060024</MsgId><CreDtTm></CreDtTm></root> |
```

There are other ways to modify an XML, for example using `replace`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#replace